# Pythonic way to intercept calls to a function?

Tags: python, testing, macros, scope

For testing things that query the environment (e.g., `os.getenv`, `sys.version`, etc.), it's often more convenient to make the queries lie than to actually fake up the environment. Here's a context manager that does this for one `os.getenv` call at a time:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from contextlib import contextmanager
import os

@contextmanager
def fake_env(**fakes):
    '''fakes is a dict mapping variables to their values. In the
    fake_env context, os.getenv calls try to return out of the fakes
    dict whenever possible before querying the actual environment.
    '''

    global os
    original = os.getenv

    def dummy(var):
        try: return fakes[var]
        except KeyError: return original(var)

    os.getenv = dummy
    yield
    os.getenv = original

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print os.getenv('HOME') 
    with fake_env(HOME='here'):
        print os.getenv('HOME') 
    print os.getenv('HOME')
```

But this only works for `os.getenv` and the syntax gets a bit clunky if I allow for functions with multiple arguments. I guess between `ast` and `code`/`exec`/`eval` I could extend it to take the function to override as a parameter, but not cleanly. Also, I would then be on my way to Greenspun's Tenth. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could easily just pass `os.getenv` itself as the first argument, then analyze it in the context manager *much* more simply than `ast`, `code`, etc etc:

```
>>> os.getenv.__name__
'getenv'
>>> os.getenv.__module__
'os'
```

After that, for reasonably general purpose use, you could have the result object to be returned, or a mapping from arguments (probably tuples thereof) to results.  The `faker` context manager could also optionally accept a callable to be used for faking.

For example, with maximum simplicity:

```
import sys

def faker(original, fakefun):

    original = os.getenv
    themod = sys.modules[original.__module__]
    thename = original.__name__

    def dummy(*a, **k):
        try: return fakefun(*a, **k)
        except BaseException: return original(*a, **k)

    setattr(themod, thename, dummy)
    yield
    setattr(themod, thename, original)
```

Your specific example could become:

```
with faker(os.getenv, dict(HOME='here').__getitem__):
   ...
```

Of course, a little more complexity may be warranted if e.g. you want to propagate certain exceptions rather than punting to the original function, or shortcut some common cases where providing a fakefun callable is clunky, and so on.  But there's no reason such a general faker need be *much* more complex than your specific one.

Comment: So this is the Python time machine. Right, the missing piece in my head was how to extract the module and name from the function itself rather than its string name (e.g., `'os.getenv'`). Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand this at the time, but it's actually very important to re-import the module, isn't it? If, say, you just look it up in `locals()`/`globals()`, then it breaks when the module is imported under a different name (e.g., `import csv as bob`).

Comment: @Wang, `original.__module__` won't be affected by that `as` clause anyway -- try it!

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. `original.__module__` will always use the standard name, and `sys.modules` will always map from the standard name to the module. But `locals()`/`globals()` might list it under the `as`-clause name.

Comment: @Wang, right -- sys.modules is your friend, exactly in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write your own (fake) `sys`, `os`, &c. modules?

```
import fakeSys as sys
```